# Dar diferentes parametros a un método

Tags: java, poo

Estoy haciendo un programa de reservas de asientos con poo y jframe, hice una matriz que hace referencia a los asientos y va de la mano con el asiento y fila que se escoja. El problema es que el usuario escogerá varios asientos y no se como dar de parametro todos esos asientos al método para que se guarden en la matriz y luego se muestren los asientos ocupados y libres.

```
public class cAsientos {

//Atributos
private int fila,columna;
private int[][] asientos = new int[3][6];

//Constructores
public cAsientos(int fila, int columna, int total_asientos) {
    this.fila = fila;
    this.columna = columna;
}
    
//Metodos
public int[][] reservaAsiento(){
    String cadena="";
        if (asientos[fila-1][columna-1]==0){
            asientos[fila-1][columna-1]=1;
        }

    return asientos;
}

public String muestraAsiento(){
    String cadena="";
    for(int i=0;i<asientos.length-1;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<asientos[0].length-1;j++)
                cadena+=asientos[i][j]+"\t";
                cadena+="\n";
    }
    return cadena;
}
```

}

Comment: Haz un for, lanzando el metodo por cada asiento.

Comment: El metodo reservaAsiento no toma ningun parametro, asi que imagino que no puedes seleccionar que fila/columna quieres...

Comment: public int[][] reservaAsiento(int fila, int columna){}
Puedes agregar tantos metodos como necesites, si los parametros son distintos, no afecta el codigo.

Comment: En que cada asiento puse el metodo ReservaAsiento(), pero, por ejemplo, si seleccioné 2 asientos, cuando muestro la matriz solo aparece el ultimo asiento reservado y no los 2

Comment: Modifica tu codigo y haz un ejemplo mas concreto con un resultado esperado (una foto, o un garabato, cualquier cosa), porque no comprendo tu idea al 100% para darte una respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te planteo esta idea : Desde mi punto de vista, al tratar los asientos con filas y columnas y usar un array bidimensional sera mas "tedioso" poder trabajar con ello.

Codigo nuevo :

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Asientos {

  //Yo utilizo un hashmap pero puedes utilizar el que veas conveniente, 
  //segun las necesidades de tu app

  private HashMap<Integer,Boolean> asientos = new HashMap();
    
  //Metodos
  protected void reservaAsientos(Integer asiento, Boolean estado ){
    
    asientos.put(asiento, estado);
    

  } 

  protected void estadoAsientos(){
    //Este bucle imprime por pantalla el estado de los asientos, pero tu 
    //podrias devolver lo que quisieras 
    for(Integer a : asientos.keySet()){
        System.out.printf("el estado del asiento numero %d  es : %B ", a.intValue(), asientos.get(a));
    }

  }

}
```

Main :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Asientos asientos = new Asientos();

        Integer num = 1;

        Boolean estado = true;

        asientos.reservaAsientos(num, estado);
        asientos.estadoAsientos();

    }
}
```

De esta forma obtendrías una forma mas clara de trabajar con los asientos, ya que estos solo tienen dos estados : ocupado(false) o libre(true)

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo!!